# Avoid Jquery self calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I got below a Jquery function to switch between two buttons simultaneously but it's a "dirty" way of writing the code my boss will say. I don't wanna call the functions or no passing in Jquery parameter, is the there a simple or better way to write this function since i'm totally new to programming?
Below the Jquery

```
var startStopBtn = function () {

    var startBtn = $('#timerStart');
    var stopBtn = $('#timerStop').hide();

    var Start = function () {
       startBtn.hide();
       stopBtn.show();
    };

   var Stop = function () {
       var remarks2 = $(".textArea-one").val();
       if (remarks2 !== "") {
         startBtn.show();
         stopBtn.hide();
       }
   };
   return {
      Start: Start,
      Stop: Stop
   };
}(jQuery);
jQuery('#timerStart').on('click', startStopBtn.Start);
jQuery('#timerStop').on('click', startStopBtn.Stop);
```

Comment: It appears you're asking for a code review, which would be appropriate on [codereview.se]. Please review [ask], as this appears to be a highly opinionated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think code could be done in many ways, this is just one of them.

Looks like first you want to hide the stopBtn so create a function to do this. Call that function on page load or create a funtion and call it when the page loads. Here I create a function that you should call whenever you want. If you don't want to do that, just delete that function.

Then make two diferent functions that are done when you "click" #timerStart or #timerStop.

This is my version but i'm sure it can be improved:

```
    function startStopBtn(){
        $('#timerStop').hide();
    };

    $('#timerStart').on('click', function(){
        $('#timerStart').hide();
        $('#timerStop').show();
    });

    $('#timerStop').on('click', function(){
       var remarks2 = $(".textArea-one").val();
           if (remarks2 !== "") {
             $('#timerStart').show();
             $('#timerStop').hide();
           } 
    });
```